# In Python, can I monkeypatch upstream dependencies?

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, monkeypatching

Say the `setup.py` of my Python package includes *foo* (available on PyPi) in its `install_requires` list, and *foo* in turn includes *bar* (also available on PyPi) in its own `install_requires` list.

Let's further say I've discovered a bug in *bar*, which I've fixed and have created a patch. But the developers of *bar* are lazy or mean or think it's a feature, and haven't accepted the patch.

I need this patch to *bar* in order for my code to work, and I don't have time to harass, bribe or cajole the developers. My fork of *bar* exists in GitHub, so I could theoretically reference it as `git+https://github.com/me/bar.git`.

When my package is installed, and it comes time for *foo*'s dependencies to be acquired, I would like for *foo* to install my personal fork of *bar* rather than the one available of PyPi. Is there a way to make this happen from my package's `setup.py`, or do I also have to fork *foo* in order to fiddle with its dependencies?

I found [this discussion on the distutils mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-October/022963.html) during my travels, which makes me think the answer is a "no" -- but I thought I'd ask!

Comment: In the requirements.txt, you can tell pip to install from a git repo directly. This is not the cleanest but if you have no choice...